# Will freezing a bottle of vermouth change it's quality, life length or properties?

Tags: freezing, alcohol, wine

I accidentally froze an unopened bottle of white Vermouth. I've read that opening the bottle will cause the vermouth to slowly oxidase and you should finish the bottle within a month or so. How is it with a frozen bottle - does that matter?

What about regular wine? Will the freezing/thawing of a bottle reduce how long it will stay OK for drinking or can I simply thaw it up slowly and treat it as if it was never frozen?

Thank you!

Comment: You managed to freeze an entire unopened bottle?  That's actually pretty impressive on its own.  I'm presuming it wasn't made of glass?

Comment: @logophobe there is nothing difficult about freezing a glass bottle. It won't burst every time. Also, bottles with fizzy wines are much sturdier than standard wine bottles.

Comment: @logophobe Yes :) It's actually glass yeah. Was glad it didn't burst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've frozen bottles of vermouth many times. There is no issue with just letting it thaw out in the normal way. In fact you can wait until it's partly thawed, give it a good shake, and hey presto, vermouth slushy, which goes in some cocktails rather well. Fortified wines do slowly oxidise on exposure to the atmosphere, but this is greatly slowed by the alcohol content. Historically this was one the principle reasons for fortifying wines - so that they store better and last longer.